# Kotlin Generic List Parsing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, kotlin-extension, rx-kotlin

I was looking other questions but this one is using a different method.

I’m using MVVM in my Android app.

Actually this is the way that I’m getting data from my server:

- Inject dataManager into viewModel.
- viewModel calls dataManager->fetchUsers
- fetchUsers make request to server and return an Observable of Several which in this case should be Several but it’s generic.
- viewModel subscribe to this request and expect a Several.
- At this point everything works besides Several doesn’t have a list of User. This several have a list of LinkedTreeMap

[image]

I tried to change my dataManager to return a string then map the response in my viewModel but the thing with this is that I will have to do that in every request.

Also I tried to map the request in my dataManager but I got the same link tree map array.

The thing with TypeToken approach is that I have to map in my viewModel.

**UPDATED**

UsersViewModel

```
 private fun fetchUsers() {
        isLoading.set(false)
        compositeDisposable += dataManager.GET<User>(classJava = User::class)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe( { response ->
                    isLoading.set(false)
                   // Here the response should be a several with a list of users.
                }, { err ->
                    isLoading.set(false)
                })
    }
```

GET function:

```
 override fun <T> GET(classJava: KClass<*>): Single<Several<T>> {

    return Rx2AndroidNetworking.get("EndPoint")
            .addHeaders("Authorization",  apiHeader.protectedAPIHeader.accessToken!!)
            .setOkHttpClient(APIClient.getUnsafeClient())
            .build()
             // Also I tested with
             // .getObjectSingle(Several::class.java) // The thing is that I can't assign the type <T> with this approach.
            .stringSingle
            .map {

                val fromJSON = fromJson<Several<T>>(it)
                fromJSON

            }
}
```

fromJson function:

```
inline fun <reified T> fromJson(json: String): T = Gson().fromJson(json, object: TypeToken<T>() {}.type)
```

Several.kt

```
data class Several<T>(val items: MutableList<T>)
```

If I change my GET function to return a String then in UsersViewModel I add a .map like this

```
private fun fetchUsers() {
        isLoading.set(false)
        compositeDisposable += dataManager.GET<User>(classJava = User::class)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .map(
                    val severalUsers = fromJson<Several<User>>(it)
                    severalUsers 

                )
                .subscribe( { response ->
                    isLoading.set(false)
                   // usersLiveData.value = response
                }, { err ->
                    Log.e("tag", "Ocurred some error")
                    isLoading.set(false)
                })
    }
```

Then I would have a list of Users as expected but What I dont want to do is map the response in UsersViewModel because I would have to do in every single request that expect a list of items.

Is there any way that I could get a several object without map in my viewmodel?

Comment: Can you show more code? I mean process of getting data starting from viewModel to getting data in subscriber, will be easier to get the context of your problem.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just updated the question